# Restrict access to certain rows in table based on user

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, how do I restrict access to certain rows (hide data) in tables based on the users identity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic / normal way to do this would be:

- prevent that user (or group) from accessing the base table
- define a view on top of that table that shows only the rows these users are supposed to see
- give those users SELECT permission on the view